# Property 'focusedItem' does not exist on type '{ focusedItem: {

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code:

`const { focusedItem } = useFocusData<{ focusedItem: Asset }>(focusedItemDataKey);`

Which throws the TypeScript error:

> Property 'focusedItem' does not exist on type '{ focusedItem: { id:

But you can see from the error itself that it actually does exist. The hook `useFocusData` returns the generic that you pass it, in this case an object with property `focusData` of type `Asset`.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Not sure why this has been voted down and suggested to close - if you think it's a bad question, say why - it's a legitimate problem

Comment: What does the rest of the error look like? If there's a `| null` or `| undefined` at the end, that would explain the error.